# replace specific columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to loop through dataset and replace specific columns value with one the same [value]
[image]

The whole dataset has 91164 rows.
The case here i need to replace `vec_red` ,`vec_greem`, `vec_blue` with `new_data`

`new_data` has shape of `(91164,)` and its number of appearance equals index of my dataframe.
For e.g. last item is

[image]

This `1` need to be value in `val_red` , `val_blue`, `val_green`.
So I want to loop through whole dataframe and replace the calues in columns from 3 to 5.

What I have is :

```
label_idx = 0
for i in range(321):
    for j in range(284):
      (sth here)   = new_data[label_idx]
        label_idx += 1
```

The case here is that I am updating my pixel values after filtration. Thank you.

The shape of 91164 is result of multiplication 321 * 284. These are my pixel values in an RGB image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping over rows of a dataframe is a code smell. If the 3 columns must receive the same values, you can do it in one single operation:

```
df[['vec_red', 'vec_green', 'vec_blue']] = np.transpose(
    np.array([new_data, new_data, new_data]))
```

Demo:

```
np.random.seed(0)

nx = 284
ny = 321
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_indices': [i for j in range(ny) for i in range(nx)],
                   'y_indices': [j for j in range(ny) for i in range(nx)],
                   'vec_red': np.random.randint(0, 256, nx * ny),
                   'vec_green': np.random.randint(0, 256, nx * ny),
                   'vec_blue': np.random.randint(0, 256, nx * ny)
                   })

new_data = np.random.randint(0, 256, nx * ny)
print(df)
print(new_data)
df[['vec_red', 'vec_green', 'vec_blue']] = np.transpose(
    np.array([new_data, new_data, new_data]))
print(df)
```

It gives as expected:

```
       x_indices  y_indices  vec_red  vec_green  vec_blue
0              0          0      172        167       100
1              1          0       47         92       124
2              2          0      117         65       174
3              3          0      192        249        72
4              4          0       67        108       144
...          ...        ...      ...        ...       ...
91159        279        320       16        162        42
91160        280        320      142        169       145
91161        281        320      225         81       143
91162        282        320      106         93        68
91163        283        320       85         65       130

[91164 rows x 5 columns]
[ 32  48 245 ...  26  66  58]
       x_indices  y_indices  vec_red  vec_green  vec_blue
0              0          0       32         32        32
1              1          0       48         48        48
2              2          0      245        245       245
3              3          0        6          6         6
4              4          0      178        178       178
...          ...        ...      ...        ...       ...
91159        279        320       27         27        27
91160        280        320      118        118       118
91161        281        320       26         26        26
91162        282        320       66         66        66
91163        283        320       58         58        58

[91164 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: How can I display it as an image?